# What action is picking up your disarmed weapon while Prone?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, opportunity-attack, prone

I have a fighter with Two-Weapon Fighting. In a Full Attack Action, I make a successful Trip attempt with my first attack and a successful Disarm attempt with the second Attack.

The foe is now prone and disarmed. Does he need to use a move action to pick up the weapon, provoking an Attack of Opportunity, or is it a free action because the weapon is next to him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Picking up an item is neither faster nor easier because a creature's prone

A prone creature doesn't pick up an item in less time than a standing creature, and a prone creature still provokes an attack of opportunity from each foe that threatens the creature when it attempts to pick up an item.

Despite the weapon being right there on the ground and in the [prone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Prone) creature's space, if the creature has been the victim of the combat maneuver [disarm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Disarm), then the typical creature *must* take a move action that provokes attacks of opportunity to pick up the weapon. (Also see the Table: [Actions in Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Actions-In-Combat) and its short accompanying FAQ entry.)

---

***Note:*** The fighter in question has picked here the right order in which to execute these maneuvers: If the fighter's [trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Trip) combat maneuver succeeds and renders the foe prone, when the fighter makes the disarm attempt against the prone foe, [Combat Modifiers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Combat-Modifiers) has the foe suffer a −4 penalty to his [Combat Maneuver Defense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Combat-Maneuver-Defense) score as "[a]ny penalties to a creature's AC also apply to its CMD.")

Comment: Yes im aware of the -4, that's why i want to do it in that order, first trip then disarm.

Comment: @Wyrmwood i've missread your comment haha. I want it in that order because the defender has -4 cmd, not the disarm attempt

Comment: Yeah. I read it wrong.

Comment: Speaking of action orders, it could also be pointed out that an enemy could instead stand (still provoking unless it has Kip Up or a similar ability), 5 foot step, and pick up their weapon (which would provoke from their new location, not where the item was dropped). Assuming, of course, that they are willing to give up their Standard Action attack at -4.